# Measure of distance with Mapbox gl JS

Tags: jquery, distance, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox gl JS function not working

Hello everybody,

I use Mapbox gl JS  and am trying to measure a distance via lnglat objects of the library
official doc here : https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#lnglat

i create two latlng objects and i call the function to get the distance between them. veri simple, like in the doc, but it sdoesn't work : the browser says tha lnglat is not a function.

Below the code, if someone has an idea .... Thanks :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>brouillon</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no'/>

        <!--    {#    BOOTSTRAT CSS#}-->
        <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" rel="stylesheet">
            <!--    {# JQUERY #}-->
            <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
                    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <!--    {# AJJAX POPPER.JS #}-->
            <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
                    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <!--    {# BOOTSTRAP JS #}-->
            <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
                    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <!--    {#    MAPBOX JS AND CSS #}-->
            <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
            <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet'/>


            <!--MAPBOX GEOCODER-->
            <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
            <link rel='stylesheet'
                  href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css'
                  type='text/css'/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1>distance test</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div id='map2' style='width: 800px; height: 600px;'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="id-action">action</button>

        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // your token below
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'your token here'; 
            let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map2', // container id
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [-73.968565, 40.779897], // New york
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });

            $("#id-action").click(function () {
            let new_york = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-74.0060, 40.7128);
            let los_angeles = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-118.2437, 34.0522);
            let foo = new_york.distanceTo(los_angeles);
            alert(foo);
        })
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not explicitly specified in the [changelog](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md), distanceTo seems to have only appeared in 1.8.0. Try https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.0/mapbox-gl.js or https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js (the latest one) instead.